# How to get full height menu div

Tags: html, css, height, absolute

Im trying to get the navigation menu on this website (http://hester.witweb.nl) to be full height of the screen as displayed on http://hestermacrander.nl.

I tried setting multiple divs to height 100% and using absolute positioning but there is something wrong in the code somewhere that is not making this work.

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="mainwrapper">
       <div class="menu"></div>
       <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#page {
height:100%;
}

#header {
height:230px;
}

#mainwrapper {
height:100%;

}

.menu {
float:left;
height:100%;
}

.content {
float:left;
width:650px;
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you included relevant CSS and HTML for us to test and experiment with, instead of having to look through the website's source.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There is no code sample provided, so I will do my best to create an illustrative one:

```
div.navmenu {
    height: 100vh; /* sets the height to be 100% of the viewport height */
}
```

This is new as part of the CSS3 specification. `vh` and `vw` are units where each 1 unit is equal to 1% of the viewport (window) height or width, respectively.

Comment: Thought it would be useful to link browser support: [http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)